# Uncaught Error: Script error for *.dart", needed by: web_entrypoint.dart

Tags: flutter

I am new bee to flutter and web.  I got follow error when i run my app in Chrome which works well in android.

```
   require.js:1959 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/project/flutter_afast/lib/model/builder.dart
   req.load @ require.js:1959
   require.js:143 Uncaught Error: Script error for "E:/project/flutter_afast/lib/model/builder.dart", needed by: web_entrypoint.dart
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
        at makeError (require.js:168)
        at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738)
```

build.dart code as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_afast/generated/l10n.dart';
import 'package:flutter_afast/model/result.dart';
import 'package:flutter_afast/model/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_afast/screen/login.dart';
import 'package:progress_dialog/progress_dialog.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';



typedef Widget SuccessCallback(BaseResult data);


ProgressDialog getCommonProgressDialog(BuildContext context){
  return ProgressDialog(
    context,
    type: ProgressDialogType.Normal,
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    isDismissible: false,
//      customBody: LinearProgressIndicator(
//        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blueAccent),
//        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
//      ),
  );
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class AsyncBuilder extends FutureBuilder<BaseResult> {
  Widget loading ;
  Widget onError ;
  final Future<BaseResult> f;
  final SuccessCallback callback;



  AsyncBuilder(this.f, this.callback, {this.loading, this.onError})
      : super(
            future: f,
            initialData: Result(BaseResult.RESULT_LOADING, null, null),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {

              Widget w;
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                if(onError == null){
                  w = Center(
                    child: Text(S.of(context).prompt_load_failed),
                  );
                }else{
                  w = onError;
                }

              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data.status == Status.LOADING) {
                  if(loading == null){
                    w =  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }else{
                    w= loading;
                  }
                } else if (snapshot.data.status == Status.SUCCESS) {
                  w = callback.call(snapshot.data);
                } else if (snapshot.data.status == Status.UNAUTHENTICATED) {
                  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) =>   {
                    value.setString(UserModel.KEY_TOKEN, null)
                  });
                  w = MyLogin();
                }
              }
              return w;
            });
}
```

Any idea for this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by checking that the imports in the darts file were using the package-relative path (`package:app/...`) instead of your local path ("`E:/..`"). That solved it for me.